# How can I arrange sorted data in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I used iphones address book data in my app ,i sorted that data and arranged in UITableViewController,but now i want to make same look as of address book means sorted in GroupedStyle having initial character as heading of section .and suggestion plz

Comment: you wanting something like following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665310/sort-data-and-display-in-uitableview-on-iphone/4665728#4665728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the tableView methods that are

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

for section headers and for this this you also have to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

By doing this your table data can be viewed in grouped style.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like following to sort the contacts:

```
    NSArray* tempArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"contacts"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first_name"
                                                 ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    contactsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempArray  sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
```

From the use NSPredicate to pick the contacts and add them to section that you want.

Comment: I have already sorted the array but now i want to put in table as grouped style having first character as section heading

Comment: First have an Array that store strings from A to Z. Create 26 sections. Then use the delegate method "- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section" and set the string in this method. Create array of arrays sorting the firstname using filters. (i'm little busy now and may not be able to provide the code) Do some research on nspredicate to create different arrays......